# How to check if a string contains words

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm not really advanced at coding/javascript so I hired someone to code a function that should check SMS messages (within a web service called Twilio) and determine if it contains positive or negative words.

He wrote the code below. However, the problem is that this code only detects a sub-string and not a word.

In this case it doesn't make a distinction between the word "No" and "Nowhere" or "Yes" and "Yesterday". So I need it to only check for the words and not just the letters.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's the code:

```js
var event = {
  Body: 'this is a test with some words'
};

var str = event.Body.toLowerCase();
var positive_pattern = ['yes', 'yeah', 'sure', 'of course', 'yup', 'i do', 'i have', 'certainly', 'yep', 'you bet'];
var negative_pattern = ['no', 'nope', 'stop'];

function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });
  return (value > 0);
}

var positive = contains(str, positive_pattern);
var negative = contains(str, negative_pattern);
console.log({
  positive,
  negative
});

callback = (_, msg) => console.log(msg);

if (positive === true && negative === false)
  callback(null, 'positive');

else if (positive === false && negative === true)
  callback(null, 'negative');

else if (positive === true && negative === true)
  callback(null, 'negative');

else if (positive === false && negative === false)
  callback(null, 'unknown');
```

Comment: You need to split your input into words, and check if one of them is a match.

Comment: eg. `function contains(target, pattern) {const words = target.split(" "); return pattern.some(test=>words.includes(test));}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression word boundary `\b`.

```
function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b")).test(target);
  });
  return (value > 0);
}
```

Since you only require one of the words to match, you can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
function contains(target, pattern) {
  return pattern.some(word=>new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b")).test(target));
}
```

If the words might contain regular expression metacharacters, you can split the `target` on whitespace characters and check if the resulting array contains each word.

```
function contains(target, pattern){
    const parts = target.split(/\s+/);
    return pattern.some(word=>parts.includes(word));
}
```

Comment: The last one seems to have solved it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Julian No problem.

Comment: Ah it doesn't seem to detect things like "No." or "Yes." The other two suggestions don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Julian It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/twq0k4no/

Comment: Very strange. Here is my code + result https://ibb.co/N1tDW65 https://ibb.co/yfgdCqV

Comment: @Julian Please create a reproducible example in JSFiddle.

Comment: Is it possible that this works differently because the code is run within the Twilio environment?

Comment: @Julian Try to just provide a minimal example that still produces an error. It does not have to include all your code.

Comment: @Julian I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

We need to make sure the *whole word* is matched, which we can do by splitting the target string up by whitespace.

```js
var positive_pattern = ['yes', 'yeah', 'sure', 'of course', 'yup', 'i do', 'i have', 'certainly', 'yep', 'you bet'];
var negative_pattern = ['no', 'nope', 'stop'];

function contains(target, patterns) {
  // at least one match?
  return patterns.filter(
    word => target.split(/\s+/).includes(word)
  ).length > 0;
}

function Test(callback, str) {
  var positive = contains(str, positive_pattern);
  var negative = contains(str, negative_pattern);

  if (positive === true && negative === false)
    callback(null, 'positive');

  else if (positive === false && negative === true)
    callback(null, 'negative');

  else if (positive === true && negative === true)
    callback(null, 'negative');

  else if (positive === false && negative === false)
    callback(null, 'unknown');
}

const testCallback = (_, msg) => console.log(msg);
const tests = [
  'yesterday nowhere', // unknown
  'yes',               // positive
  'yes no yeah',       // negative (mixed)
  'nope'               // negative
];

for (const testString of tests)
  Test(testCallback, testString);
```